# XML Package error in 2.12, but not 2.10

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I am using the XML package in R to read the HTML tables from a page.  In 2.12.1, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in names(ans) = header : 
  'names' attribute [24] must be the same length as the vector [19]
```

However, when I run the same code snippet in 2.10, there are no errors and everything parses (almost) fine.  I say almost because the column names are taken from the first row of the table, but I can get around that.

Here is my code:

```
## load the libraries
library(XML)

## set the season
SEASON <- "2011"

## create the URL
URL <- paste("http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_", SEASON, "_goalies.html", sep="")

## grab the page -- the table is parsed nicely -- why work 2.10, but not 2.12.1?
tables <- readHTMLTable(URL)
```

Any help you can provide will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this problem occurs because of the move to v2.12.1 or not.  I tried it on 2.12.1 and get the same error.

However, the error might also occur because something in the HTML changed.  I had a look at the HTML source on that page, and the table isn't as well formed as one would hope.  There are two problems with the HTML table: 1) the first header row contains merged columns, and 2) the header row gets repeated.

It is the first of these that causes your code to return an error.  The data rows are of length 19, but the header consists of two rows, one of lenght 19 and one of length 5, i.e. 24 in total.  It is this discrepancy that throws your error.

I haven't been able to scrape this page using the readHTMLTable() function.  But here is my solution using the tools in scrapeR and XML:

```
# load the libraries
library(XML)
library(scrapeR)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)

# scrape and parse page
page <- scrape(url=URL, parse=TRUE)
raw <- xpathSApply(page[[1]], "//table//tr", xmlValue)
# split strings at each line break
rows <- strsplit(raw, "\n")
# now check for longest row length, and discard all short rows
rowlength <- (laply(rows, length))
rows <- rows[rowlength==max(rowlength)]
# unlist each row
rows <- laply(rows, function(x)unlist(x))
# trim white space
rows <- aaply(rows, c(1,2), str_trim)
# convert to data frame
df <- as.data.frame(rows, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# read names from first row
names(df) <- laply(df[1, ], str_trim)
# remove all rows without a numerix index
df <- df[which(!is.na(as.numeric(df$Rk))), ]
df
```

The code is a little bit messy, and the table isn't clean, since the all of the data are character vectors, rather than numeric.

But at least this means you have the data in a format that you can process further.